# How to define symfony routes with seperating "-" between 2 parameters?

Tags: symfony, routes

I have a symfony routing defined:

```
route_name:
    path:     /foo/{slug}-{jobId}
```

slug: can be `bar-92-test-123`

jobId: integer

What are the right regular expressions for slug and jobId for Symfony to handle the route correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works with the following requirements:

```
requirements:
    slug: '([a-z0-9]+[-]?)+'
    jobId: '\d+'
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally the following regular expression can cover your need:

```
(.*)-(\d+)$
```

So it seems the last `$` sign can solve your issue as well.

Comment: Not bad, but the first part now allow "/". And your response is for using only one parameter.
So the requirements for slug can be the same as the default, [^/]+ and for jobId, \d+.
If you want to be strict, you can use someting like this for the slug "([a-z0-9]+[-]?)+" to allow only lowercase, number and separate by a "-"